# Rails application with tailwind css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I have created rails application and setup tailwind css using following guide: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/ruby-on-rails. I was wondering if this setup is good enough to create web application or setting up JavaScript is recommended.

Thank you

Comment: It is more flexible to use css-bundling gem with tailwind

Comment: @mechnicov, hmm does that mean you don't recommend setting up JS?